# How early should I start asking professors for a summer position?

Tags: etiquette, supervision, communication

I am a high school student and have several professors at colleges nearby who are conducting research I find very interesting. I am going to ask them to consider letting me work under them during the summer, and maybe afterward throughout the school year. When should I ask? Should I ask in the coming weeks, to give them time to respond, or should I wait a few months until the summer is closer?

Comment: You might ask one of your high school teachers if they would vouch for you.

Comment: You are a high school student, and you want to work with people who are faculty/staff at a university or college, is that correct? Could you clarify in your question that that is what you meant by "professors"? This is a reasonable question, but it just needs some clarification, thank you.

Comment: In addition to Ellie comment, one can anticipate that the sooner is the better. There might be paperwork to be done, or someone can be faster. Also consider a country tag as for summer working of a hi-school student at a faculty does not exist everywhere.

Comment: This question was asked in December. In the United States and many other countries, professors are nearing the end of a semester and are very busy.  Then there's a string of holidays, some religious and some not.  Then comes the start of the next semester, also a busy time.  If it were I, I think I'd wait until near the end of January in order that my request not get lost in the noise.  (Alchemista's advice is correct that sooner is better, but one should consider timing, too.)

Comment: Consider that in times like these, you might get a spontanous rejection shortly before the beginning.

Comment: @BobBrown Ah, but that's when my semester starts ...

Comment: @AzorAhai-him-  Thanks for mentioning that. OP should check the schedule(s) of the professors.

Answer (score 1):

I would look at https://www.nsf.gov/crssprgm/reu/reu_search.jsp and https://cadrek12.org for programs at universities in your area that have open applications for the upcoming spring and summer semesters. These are likely to be low-paying internships that are part of ongoing research programs NSF already funds which are going to be looking for high-achieving high-school students to participate in research. The "U" in "REU" is for "Undergraduates", so college students, but many of the programs have portions for late high-school students, too, so read carefully. Your ability to read about the program and follow instructions will help determine your acceptability to them.

*Broader Impacts*, including impacts on K-12 students are a big part of NSF grant funding, and so many NSF-funded organizations in the US have something to offer throughout the year. That being said, individual professors may not. I think you'd be better served by looking at organizations within academic institutions (museums, computing centers, laboratories, etc.) than trying to talk directly with a single professor. For the reasons noted in the comments about busy-ness, a single prof. might not have the resources to supervise a single high-school student or even assign that supervision to a grad student. Look for labs and institutions that have such programs.